# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" despite using full path

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, errno

Just wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction as I'm at complete loss of what's happening (I'm a beginner so sorry if this is blaringly obvious!).

I'm writing some code to create a photomosaic. It requires resizing photos from a database and then concating images together to create a bigger picture.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
def resize(self):
        path = "C:/Users/chloe/Desktop/Python_Stuffs/Robert_Heaton/landscape_images"
        dirs = os.listdir(path)
        new_path = Path(path, 'resized_pics')
        new_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        #etc.
        
 def concat_rows(self):
        path = "C:/Users/chloe/Desktop/Python_Stuffs/Robert_Heaton"
        new_path_concat = Path(path, 'photomosaic_images_' + im_name)
        new_path_concat.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        counter = 0
        for row in self.match_pixel_img:
            im1_path = os.path.join(self.new_path,row.pop(0))
            os.chdir(self.new_path)
            im1 = Image.open(im1_path)
            #etc.
```

In the function `resize` I create a new directory with the new resized pictures in, and then in `concat_rows` I take the resized images from the new directory and concat them. However, I'm getting this error:

```
    File "C:\Users\chloe\Desktop\Python_Stuffs\Robert_Heaton\photomosaic.py", line 95, in concat_rows
    im1 = Image.open(im1_path)

    File "C:\Users\chloe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    'C:\\Users\\chloe\\Desktop\\Python_Stuffs\\Robert_Heaton\\landscape_images\\resized_pics\\'
```

even though this is the directory I created in `resize` and I can **SEE** the directory in my files at that exact location. I'm using the fullpath so I'm really not sure what is wrong. Furthermore, when I run the code a second time it works fine so maybe it's something to do with the way Python reads lines?

If anyone could shed some light I'd be really grateful!

Comment: use `print(im1_path)` to check what you try to open in `Image.open(im1_path)` - probably you use folder name instead of file name - so you try to read folder instead image.

Comment: Why do you use `pop(0)` ? Maybe you should use `row` without `pop(0)`. - `os.path.join(self.new_path, row)`

Comment: Hi @furas, thanks for responding! `Image.open(im1_path)` was giving the fullpath to the correct file. `pop(0)` was used as at the start of each row of pixels I wanted to take only the first picture and use that as the basis to concat the rest of the pictures. I haven't solved what was happening, but I have now worked around it by putting `resize(self)` in a different file completely and running that first before running the main body.